# N+1 Primality Proving is slow

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to implement the N+1 method of proving primality. Here is my description, based on the Brillhart, Lehmer, Selfridge [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-130/S0025-5718-1975-0384673-1/), Theorem 13 and Corollary 8:

> Choose P and Q such that D = P^2 - 4*Q is not a square modulo N. Let
>   N+1 = F*R with F > R, where R is odd and the prime factorization of F
>   is known. If there exists a Lucas sequence of discriminant D with
>   U(N+1) == 0 (mod N) and gcd(U((N+1)/q), N) = 1 for each prime q
>   dividing F, then N is prime; if no such sequence exists for a given P
>   and Q, a new P' and Q' with the same D can be computed as P' = P + 2
>   and Q' = P + Q + 1 (the same D must be used for all the factors q).

I compute D as the first number in the sequence 5, -7, 9, -11, ... for which the jacobi symbol (D/N) = -1, with P = 1 and Q = (1-D)/4, and find the primes q dividing F by trial division. Here is my code, in Python, which you can see and run at [ideone.com/HVXIGR](http://ideone.com/HVXIGR); function u(p, q, m, n) returns the n'th element of the Lucas sequence U(p,q) modulo m:

```
def provePrime(n):
    f, fs, fp, r, d = 2, [], 1, n+1, 5
    while fp*fp < n:
        while r % f == 0:
            r /= f; fp *= f
            if f not in fs:
                fs.append(f)
        f += 1
    while jacobi(d, n) <> -1:
        d = (abs(d)+2) * signum(d) * -1
    p, q = 1, (1-d)/4
    print fs, d, p, q
    if gcd(d, n) > 1: return False
    if u(p, q, n, n+1) <> 0: return False
    for x in fs:
        while True:
            if gcd(u(p,q,n,(n+1)/x), n) == 1: break
            p, q = p + 2, p + q + 1
    return True
```

The problem is that for some N this is very slow because the final while loop that searches for P and Q takes a very long time. For instance, it takes over two minutes to prove the primality of 10^12+61 with D=-7.

So my questions: 1) Is my description of the algorithm correct? 2) Does my code correctly implement the algorithm? 3) How can I make it faster? 4) Can I make it faster by switching to a new D and restarting the computation? 5) If so, how can I determine when to abandon the current D and start over?

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

This code works; you can see it running at [ideone.com/HVXIGR](http://ideone.com/HVXIGR):

```
def provePrime(n):
    f, fs, fp, r, d = 2, [], 1, n+1, 5
    while fp*fp < n:
        if f*f > r:
            fs.append(r)
            break
        while r % f == 0:
            r /= f; fp *= f
            if f not in fs:
                fs.append(f)
        f += 1
    while jacobi(d, n) <> -1:
        d = (abs(d)+2) * signum(d) * -1
    p, q = 1, (1-d)/4
    if gcd(d, n) > 1: return False
    if u(p, q, n, n+1) <> 0: return False
    for x in fs:
        while True:
            if gcd(u(p,q,n,(n+1)/x), n) == 1:
                print x, p, q
                break
            p, q = p + 2, p + q + 1
    return True
```

The factorization is mildly tricky. R (initially N+1) is the number currently being factored, F is the current trial factor, FS is the current list of factors without duplicates, and FP is the current product of the factors including multiplicity (so FP in the code corresponds to F in the description). If F*F > R, then the current R is prime, so it is the last factor of N+1 and factoring is complete. Alternately, if FP*FP > N, then even though factorization isn't complete, it is sufficient to prove primality, so the factoring can be terminated.

Comment: If you are interested in speed, why are you using Python?

Comment: It is convenient to work out the algorithm in a language like Python, then implement it for real in C/GMP.

Comment: Notice Remark 2 after Theorem 13: From one Lucas sequence with 
$P_1, Q_1, \text{and }D$, another with the same D can be obtained by setting $P_2= P_1 + 2\;$ and $Q_2 = P_1+ Q_1+ 1$. 

**It is necessary to check that $(N,Q_i) = 1$.**
You do **not** check this gcd, but I do not know how much this would speed up your algorithm. Another obvious speed up would be to use only 2 and the odd f for trial in the first part.

Comment: Your initial $p$ and $q$ are 1 and 2, respectively. What are the ending values?

Comment: @gammatester: Well, it's not really necessary. If (N, Qi) > 1, then Qi | N and we have found a factorization. But assuming N is prime, that will never happen. Certainly before attempting to prove N is prime, you have done enough work to suggest that it has no small factors.

Comment: I've done some more timing tests. The slowness comes from the factorization of (10^12+61) + 1 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 7 * 47 * 168861871. Counting from 2 to 168861871 takes a long time. That means the N+1 method is not suitable for performing this primality proof. I've added code to stop early and report failure once the trial divisor reaches the square root of the remaining R. I would still appreciate confirmation that my algorithm is correct.

Comment: I had already suspected the trial division (thus the suggestion with odd f),
but you explicitly marked the final while loop as culprit (BTW you should count 'only' up to order $10^6$, but may be even this is too much for an interpreted language). I would not say
that the `N+1 method is not suitable for performing this primality proof`,
because are better methods of factorization of such 'small' $N+1$, e.g.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_SQUFOF.

Comment: Addition after edit time expired: Your trial division loop condition should be `f*f <= n`

Comment: @gammatester: Thanks for your comments; I got it working. And trial division is preferable to SQUFOF because otherwise all the factors need to be proved prime, recursively. I'm a little bit embarrassed to get the trial division wrong, because that's the simple part of the task.

Comment: How do I mark my own question SOLVED? Do I write a solution and accept it myself?

Comment: This is a little late to the party, but: the $N+1$ test is _not_ meant to be a general-purpose test; as suggested by the paper, it is specifically meant for those $N$ for which $N+1$ is very 'smooth' (i.e., has many small prime factors).  For instance, numbers of the form $2^a3^b-1$ would be good candidates for this test, as would _Woodall numbers_.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely-test.

It does not require factorizations and is therefore much faster.

Comment: References, other pointers?

Comment: I want to implement the N+1 test today. I'll implement other tests on another day.